# How can I create a directory and change my working directory to the new directory?

Tags: command-line

I'm seeking a way to create directory and change my present working directory to newly created directory just by using a single command. How can I do this?

i.e Instead of doing

```
user@Computer:~$ mkdir NewDirectory
user@Computer:~$ cd NewDirectory
user@Computer:~/NewDirectory$
```

I want to do

```
user@computer:~$ **command** NewDirectory
user@Computer:~/NewDirectory$
```

What can the **command** be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you really want it to be just one command, I suggest adding something like this to your `.bashrc`:

```
md () { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$1"; }
```

Entering `md foo` on the command line will then create a directory called `foo` and `cd` into it immediately afterwards. Please keep in mind, that you will have to reload your `.bashrc` for the changes to take effect (i.e. open a new console, or run `source ~/.bashrc`).

Cf. http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3613/create-a-directory-and-change-into-it-at-the-same-time for possible alternatives, too.

Answer (score 23):

`mkdir "NewDirectory" && cd "NewDirectory"`

- The part behind the `&&` will only execute if the 1st command succeeds.
- It is called a [Lists of Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) in the Bash manual.
- There is also a shorthand version:

  ```
  mkdir "NewDirectory" && cd "$_"
  ```
- Example from command line:

  ```
  $ false && echo "yes"
  $ true && echo "yes"
  yes
  ```
- (edit) Add " to the commands since the directory might contain a space.

Comment: `mkdir "NewDir" && cd "$_"` works great than `mkdir "NewDir" && cd "NewDir"` as auto complete doesn't work. BTW what is "$_" ?

Comment: More than that it would be quite handy if we can attach a switch to `mkdir` to change to new directory created.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect $_ see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists  Regarding that last one: nobody is stopping you from using an alias or a function inside `.bashrc` ;)

Answer (score 8):

There's no built-in function for that, but you can use shell functionality to help you not have to type the argument of the `cd` command again after running `mkdir`:

- Type `cd` , then <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) to insert the last argument from the previous command.
- `cd !$` executes `cd` on the last argument of the previous command.
- Press <kbd>Up</kbd> to recall the previous command line, then edit it to change `mkdir` into `cd`.

You can define a simple make-and-change-directory function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
mkcd () { mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"; }
```

Reload your `.bashrc` (`. ~/.bashrc`) or restart bash, and now you can type `mkcd new-directory`.

This simple version fails in some unusual cases involving weird directory names or `..` and symbolic links. Here's one that does. For explanations, see [the Unix & Linux version of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th).

```
mkcd () {
  case "$1" in
    /*) mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1";;
    */../*) (cd "./${1%/../*}/.." && mkdir -p "./${1##*/../}") && cd "$1";;
    ../*) (cd .. && mkdir -p "${1#.}") && cd "$1";;
    *) mkdir -p "./$1" && cd "./$1";;
  esac
}
```

Comment: My +1 is specifically for the Bash-specific references to the last command's arguments.

Comment: +1 for over engineering. Excelsior! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir -p "as/many dirs/as you/want" && cd "$_"
```

there is a solution listed above (same as my solution but with no -p option), but I think it has a few pitfalls.

```
man mkdir
...
-p, --parents
       no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
...
```

This gives us two benefits:

1. We can create as many subdirectories as needed in one go
2. If the directory exists, it will not throw an error, and we will be still able to switch to the existing directory.

`&& cd "$_"` will change to the newly created directory, since `$_` hold the value returned my `mkdir`

Comment: this works for me