# How to create a new directory and switch into it from the command line?

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command, mkdir

Using the command line, how can I create new directory and navigate into it?

For example, I would like to create a new directory named **CSIS536** under my home directory, and change to the directory.

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. Your favorite Search Engine will happily answer these questions, and will happily refer you to appropriate tutorials to help you climb the learning curve and thrive in a command-line environment. If I'm mistaken, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1248045/edit) and I'm happy to revisit.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This seems like some sort of exercise you're trying to complete, but the way you've formed the question is not very clear. Do have a look at the intro tour (https://askubuntu.com/tour) if you haven't already, and try to look at similar questions to get a feel for best practices.

Comment: This question has the answer you are seeking: https://askubuntu.com/questions/249314/how-can-i-create-a-directory-and-change-my-working-directory-to-the-new-director

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the question you linked to is not exactly a duplicate because it specifically asks how to do everything in a single command. I searched as well, and I have to say I was a bit surprised not to find an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Ratler I retracted my duplicate close vote and simply posted a comment pointing out how the link to a question that contains the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new directory from the command line, you can use the [`mkdir` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkdir) as such:

```
mkdir name_of_new_directory [name_of_new_directory_2] ...
```

You can switch into a directory from the command line using the [`cd` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) as such:

```
cd name_of_existing_directory
```

---

Applying the above to your example, you can use:

```
mkdir ~/CSIS536
```

The tilde (~) is a symbol that corresponds to your home directory, whatever that might be in your system. For example, if your home directory is "/home/myusername", then the above command is equivalent to:

```
mkdir /home/myusername/CSIS536
```

You can, then, use the `cd` command to switch into the newly-created directory:

```
cd ~/CSIS536
```

Also, if you'll be working with Ubuntu or GNU/Linux in general, it'd be a good idea to get your head around the [directory structure](https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/) and [absolute vs relative paths](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix/), so look into that.

Comment: On a side note when you are in a script `mkdir -p` is a good idea to keep it from crashing. +1 for your answer and nuisance of original voting to close question. On a second side note when I take the time to answer a question I generally upvote it. *hint*

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I usually upvote questions that I answer, too. But, I think, we can all agree that this was not a question that deserved upvoting. At least, I didn't downvote it!